# Why a collection generated by getElementByClassName is considered by js as of 0 length while it is not, especially when console.loged

Tags: javascript

There is something that I really need to understand and couldn't find the answer by googling it.

In my index.html DOM, I have a simple div (let's call it "indexDiv").

I have another html file in my project file (let's call it non-index.html, containing a very long html code generated by Word.

The html in non-index.html is contained in 3 divs having the same className:"DivClassName".

With js, I append the 3 divs in non-index.html, to the indexDiv of my DOM.

somewhere in my js code, I have the following `function`

```
function collection() {
    var myCollection= document.getElementsByClassName("DivClassName");// i.e., a collection of the 3 divs appended to the DOM from the non-index.html
    console.log(myCollection);
    console.log(myCollection.length);
    if (myCollection.length > 0) {
      console.log(myCollection);
    }
  }
```

The first `console.log(myCollection)` prints a HTMLCollection of length 3 with 3 divs having the same `className`.

The second `console.log(myCollection.length)` which comes just after the first one, prints 0.

The third `console.log(myCollection)` does not get printed at all which confirms that `myCollection.length` is not > 0.

I can't understand this behavior. How the first console.log shows a collection of 3 elements (which is accurate and corresponds to the number of elements with the same className in my DOM), while javascript considers the same collection as of 0 lengths when it comes to executing any subsequent code?

I will be really thankful if someone could explain or direct me to the documentation that explains this behavior.

So many thanks.

Comment: Works fine for me.. `.length` is returning the actual length

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I met the same issue several times.

Comment: Please go through this: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Checkout the console on [this codepen](https://codepen.io/tomdickson/pen/rNOPvwJ?editors=1111) it is working for me

Comment: I reedited my question and added some more details.

Comment: What you are explaining cannot happen

Comment: I'd guess that you have a typo somewhere, so the class you are looking for is not present on any elements of the document. It would be very helpful if you could include a full working example as a snippet in your question (the button that looks like a file icon with `<>` on it).

Comment: Yet it happens. I thought this is a "hoisting" or "global scope" like aspect of js that I do not understand. I got the same issue several times. It will drive me mad.

Comment: Instead of describing code, *share* the code!

Comment: As multiple people have noted, we can not help you solve this sort of problem if you don't give us an _full_ example so we can see the same results you are getting. Use a [snippet embedded in your answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and give us a full example.

Comment: I can't share the code. The divs in question are built from a html file generated by Word. This html file is of almost 100 pages. All the code in its body is wraped in 3 divs that I append to my DOM. You can't reproduce the issue if you do not have the html from which the divs are appended to the DOM. I thought this is a well known aspect of js that I missed or did not understand.

Comment: Use your browser's debugger instead of the console. What you're seeing is the result of the live `NodeList` being updated **after** this code runs. Since the console is able to show live updates, that's what you're seeing. I bet you're running `collection()` **before** the document has finished loading

Comment: I also thing it is a question related to the actual loading of the DOM. I tried to wrap the "var myCollection= document.getElementsByClassName("DivClassName");" line in an async function before running the subsequent code, but got the same result. What do you suggest in order to be sure that the console.logs (or any other code) is not run before the the document finishes loading?

Comment: If the document is too large to use as an example, your first step in debugging the problem should probably be to _manually_ make sure that there are elements with class `DivClasName` (i.e. open the element inspector and use `Ctrl`+`F` (or `Cmd`+`F`)). If there aren't, that's the problem. If there are, delete everything else besides the script you are running, so the document is just the elements with the class and the script that tries to find them. Then, if the error still occurs, post _that_ as your example.

Comment: To ensure that the script runs after the document loads, you have two options. One is to put it at the bottom of the document, after anything that needs to exist before the script can run. The other is to put the script in a function and assign it as an event listener for the document or window's load event (i.e. something like `document.onload = function(){…};` or `window.addEventListener('load', function(){…});`).

Answer (score 1):

myCollection I think that the issue is with what you are reading from the console. Let's take this modified example:

```js
function collection() {
    var myCollection= document.getElementsByClassName("DivClassName");
    console.log(myCollection); // HTMLCollection[..., ..., ...]
    console.log(myCollection.length); // 3
    if (myCollection.length > 0) { // true
      console.log(myCollection); // HTMLCollection[..., ..., ...]
    }
}

collection();

var myCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("DivClassName");

Array.from(myCollection).forEach(function(div) {
  div.remove();
});

console.log(myCollection); // HTMLCollection []
```

In the console, the first and third logs are not going to change until you open them... then you'll see a `length: 0` line.
I know maybe this is not what's happening, but I cannot think of any other issue.

Comment: Indeed. It is an issue related to the fact that what I read from the console is somehow misleading. The issue seems to be resolved by wraping the code in a function triggered by the document.body.onload event. So many thanks for your help.